# Flex Datagrid labelFunction query

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, flex4, labelfunction

**Main.mxl**

```
<s:DataGrid dataProvider="{employeeData}"> // employeeData is an Arraycollection with predefined data


        <s:typicalItem>
            <s:DataItem firstName="Christopher" 
                        lastName="Winchester" 
                        hireDate="22/12/2013"/>
        </s:typicalItem>


        <s:columns>

            <s:ArrayList>

                <s:GridColumn labelFunction="employeeName"
                              headerText="Name"/>

                <s:GridColumn dataField="hireDate"
                              headerText="Hire Date"
                              labelFunction="dateFormat"/>
            </s:ArrayList>

        </s:columns>


    </s:DataGrid>   


<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

            [Bindable]
            private var employeeData: ArrayCollection; 


            private function employeeName(item: Object, column: GridColumn): String
            {
                return item.firstName+" "+item.lastName;
            }


        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
```

**A)** Can anyone please explain me how does Datagrid internally works with **employeeName** function? I mean, Iam not even passing 2 parameters for labelFunction, BUT still how does it get called?

**B)** Why should I use **s:ArrayList tag** inside **s:columns** tag?

Comment: Based on this question, and your previous question; I strongly recommend you read through all the Flex Docs and open up the Flex Framework Source Code to answer your questions.  I'm unclear how appropriate the "how does this work" type of questions are on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Reboog711 hi,  I have watched all these videos from here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining.html 

so, what you still suggest me to read?

Comment: Start here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex.html and here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/documentation.html .  You will learn a lot by plowing through the source code to figure out how things like the labelFunction work.

Comment: @Reboog711 : thanks Reboog! Is that necessary for me to know about this internal details? or you say that Iam doing time-waste to know about these kinda things?

Comment: It isn't necessary to be productive--and I assume most Flex Developer's don't know the internal details of how the components are created.  But, it will give you a greater depth of understanding of the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A) Can anyone please explain me how does Datagrid internally works
>   with employeeName function? I mean, Iam not even passing 2 parameters
>   for labelFunction, BUT still how does it get called?

The labelFunction is a property on the GridColumn class.  Inside the Gridcolumn there is an itemToString() function which is used to determine what the label should be for that specific instance of the column.  right out of the framework code:

```
/**
 *  @private
 *  Common logic for itemToLabel(), itemToDataTip().   Logically this code is
 *  similar to (not the same as) LabelUtil.itemToLabel().
 */
private function itemToString(item:Object, labelPath:Array, labelFunction:Function, formatter:IFormatter):String
{
    if (!item)
        return ERROR_TEXT;

    if (labelFunction != null)
        return labelFunction(item, this);

    var itemString:String = null;
    try 
    {
        var itemData:Object = item;
        for each (var pathElement:String in labelPath)
            itemData = itemData[pathElement];

        if ((itemData != null) && (labelPath.length > 0))
            itemString = (formatter) ? formatter.format(itemData) : itemData.toString();
    }
    catch(ignored:Error)
    {
    }        

    return (itemString != null) ? itemString : ERROR_TEXT;
}
```

> B) Why should I use s:ArrayList tag inside s:columns tag?

Because the data type of the columns property on the DataGrid is an IList; and the ArrayList implements the IList interface.  What you're looking at is the MXML way to create and define an ArrayList.  You'd use a slightly different approach if you wanted to create the columns in ActionScript.

Comment: Thnx a lot! BTW, can u atleast tell me what difference between function in flex and method in java? I knew anput method in Java very well (so, I dont ask you to explain on this, BUT regarding Function in Flex confusing me, is it similar like method or else what?) and Thnx for helping me out :)

Comment: If you want me to go on a history lesson I can talk about differences between a function, a method, and a subroutine, however for all practical purposes in today's world; the term subroutine isn't used; and functions and methods are used interchangeably.  The differences, for the most part, are purely academic.

Comment: @Reeboog  HI, could u also pls give ur answer, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181342/flex-id-contentgroup-query

Comment: @JoeyRiver If I see it and have something add; I'll do so. There is no need to solicit answers from people.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question: the "labelFunction" property is a reference to the function that will be invoked by the DataGrid to format the text of a cell in a column. The function will be called dynamically and the DataGrid will pass in the required parameters. The DataGrid expects a label function to always have this signature. If you fail to do so, you will get a runtime error.

Technically, a function can be called dynamically with the following syntax:

```
var anObject:MyType;
var methodName:String = "myMethod";

anObject[methodName](param1, param2);
```

or if you have a Function object

```
var myFunction:Function;
myFunction(param1, param2);
```

Comment: thanks Christophe! but my query is: how does it call that function dynamically? is that necessary for me to know about this? or you say that Iam doing time-waste to know about these kinda things?

Comment: I added an example with how a method is called dynamically. You don't need to know these internals, although it might help you at some point if you need to debug code.

Comment: Its OK Christophe, I guess its tough to explain such inner functionality until i see myself source code of it.. BTW, can u atleast tell me what difference between function in flex and method in java? I knew anput method in Java very well (so, I dont ask you to explain on this, BUT regarding Function in Flex confusing me, is it similar like method or else what?) and Thnx for helping me out :)