# Flex id contentGroup query

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

iam learning Flex and practising skins. So, i just had one doubt:

I have written one custom skin named : **ApplicationContainerSkin.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
             xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
             xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <s:State name="disabled" />
    </s:states>


    <fx:Metadata>
        [HostComponent("spark.components.Application")]
    </fx:Metadata>


    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Group horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">

        <s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"
                radiusX="10" radiusY="10">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="#CCCCCC" />
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>


        <s:Group id="contentGroup"
                 left="30" right="30" top="30" bottom="30">

        </s:Group>

    </s:Group>

</s:SparkSkin>
```

**My Doubt:**
When I removed **s:Group id="contentGroup"** , iam unable to see any content inside my application, so why is this '**contentGroup**' id necessary?

where this id predefinedly specified.? sorry if its a noob query, but iam eager to knew it.I even tried to check the source code, but I didnt found it, Could anyone tell me where it specified and how does my content render only after using this contentGroup id...? ( I mean, how it internally works? )

Awaiting your responses!

Answer (score 1):

Skinnable Spark components specify "skin parts," identified by the id.

The Application component, which you are skinning, defines 2 skin parts - contentGroup and controlBarGroup, as you can see in the documentation here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Application.html#SkinPartSummary

The Application class uses the contentGroup skin part (if it has been added in the skin) to lay out the content. Skin parts can either be required or not. The contentGroup part is not required, and therefore when you left it out, the content just did not display.

Comment: Agreed! BUT how does it display using our contentGroup? To be clear, how internally it works?

Comment: SkinnableComponent has a partAdded method. In that method, a component will check what part was added, and use it accordingly. In this case, it will use the Group to lay out the content.

Comment: The 'addElement' functions in the SkinnableContainerGroup-component and it's derivates are overwritten to add the content to the 'contentGroup' instead. So if you add something via mxml it get's written into then components 'mxmlContent' array by the compiler and is then added to the displayList via 'addElement' at runtime. This might be a bit short explanation, but that's roughly, how it works

Comment: Also note that you'll encounter `contentGroup` a lot when skinning an application, because all components that extend from `SkinnableContainer` have that particular skinpart (i.e. nearly every component that can hold other components).